# Wagtail groups, subgroups and permissions

Tags: wagtail

We are very keen on Wagtail but would like some advice on its capabilities. This is to power one large website and six smaller websites (subdomains, and independent sites).

Update: [I read the multi-site blog post](https://wagtail.io/blog/multi-site-wagtail/) which I somehow missed. I think most of our requirements below are met, with the exception of preventing some groups viewing content created by parent groups. Would be great to hear thoughts on that, and/or of those running large multi-site projects.

- One Wagtail instance containing two master groups. "Staff (A)" and "Contractors"
- `Staff A` has global access (can produce and edit content) to the main site and all six independent sites.

  - `Staff A` should be able to publish content to the main site and/or all seven sites.
- `Contractors` is split into six sub-groups. Each one only has access to view, edit and publish content into their own site. Ideally, we would have some roles who have access to more than one of these sites but not all.

From what I can see, this isn't inherently possible, but grateful if this can be confirmed.

Additionally, is this idea viable on one Wagtail instance, or should we look at two? Or seven - one for each subdomain, another for the main site?

Little diagram to try and explain my thinking more clearly.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, along the lines described in the blog post you reference. I'd recommend using a single Wagtail instance.

Feel free to ping me directly if you'd like examples of live multi-site projects. My first name @torchbox.com.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Tom - will do that. I reckon the only major mod we will need is to prevent contractors seeing other sites' content in the cms other than their own. Shouldn't be too tricky to sort

Comment: Hi @tomd - sorry to resurrect this but never heard back from you. Would love to see some examples even though we're well into development...